# How to hide empty subcategories (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

I am using the code below which show empty subcategories also which don't have any post in it and I want to hide these. Let me if it is possible and if yes then how

```
<?php
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $term_id = $term->term_id;
    $taxonomy_name = $term->taxonomy;

    $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name.' ('. $term->count. ')</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `$term->count` to check if it have any post.

```
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    if($term->count > 0){
       echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name.' ('. $term->count. ')</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked... Thank you.. 
Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024411/display-all-subcategories-in-same-parent-category-wordpress also if possible.. 
Thank you again..

Comment: @mukesh If it work , then please accept the answer :)

Comment: Done.. Thank you very very very very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have a other solution

```
$termchildren = get_terms( $taxonomy_name, array( 'hide_empty' => true, 'parent' => $term_id ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use term count to check empty category

```
 $term = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = $term->taxonomy;

$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach( $termchildren  as $child  ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    if( $term->count > 0 ) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name.' ('. $term->count. ')</a></li>';
    }
}
echo '</ul>';
```